# Unable to integrate ionic project into Mobile First

Tags: ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

The worklight studio plugin fails to identify ionic tags when I import files from my ionic project into my worklight project.

Note: My `ionic.bundle.js` and `ionic.css` load fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to not use classic Hybrid apps generated by MobileFirst Studio 7.1. Instead, create a Cordova app from the MobileFirst 7.1 CLI and integrate that app with Ionic based on the steps provided in this blog post: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/08/14/going-forward/